# Fetching SQL data and send multiple emails with nodemailer from a mysql DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, nodemailer

I'm building an email-sender app using nodemailer and MySQL DB and send multiple emails.

code:

```
let emails=  `select email from users`
db.query(emails,(err, email, fields)=>{
//   console.log(email);
})




 const options = {
     from: 'h.codetests@outlook.com',
     to: emails,
     subject: 'nodemailer test', 
     text: 'noooooodemailer test'


 }

// ? we will passe options and function of (err, info) in sendmail method
 transporter.sendMail(options, (err, info)=>{
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
     }
     console.log(`sent: ${info.response}`);
 })
```

and I got this error

```
Database is connected successfully !
Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19) 
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1001:34)    at SMTPConnection.send (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
    at sendMessage (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)
    at E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1550:9)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1490:18) 
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)      
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (E:\vs work\email sender app\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  command: 'API'
```

Is there an alternative way to send multiple emails at once? or is there a way for me to make sure my app send multiple emails from the database(MySQL)?

Comment: Print `emails` to check what they are. You need to make sure you get the emails from DB then pass them to the options of `sendMail()`